# Error:org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements using htmlunitdriver?

Tags: selenium, htmlunit-driver

I am getting this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements

when I use `HtmlUnitDriver`. It works for URL, after that when I start with

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#from_city_typeahead")).sendKeys("bangalore");
```

such statements, it gives the above error. Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide us the full code and some more explanation please?

Comment: Please provide your complete case, so others can reproduce the same error.

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code of the element you try to use?

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same action with javascript:

```
webdriver.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'new value for element')");
```

Visibility does matter in case of standard visible browsers. But it's doesnt matter for javascript in case of any of browsers.